# buffered file reader only reads first line

Tags: java, file, character, frequency

I am writing a program that reads a text file and counts the frequency of each letter
it works to count the frequency of each alphabet occurring however it only seems to read the first line of the text page?
the code reads a text file into a character array

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException 
{
 
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("readthis.txt"));        
    String s = br.readLine();
    s = s.toLowerCase();
    int l = s.length();
    char ch;

  
    System.out.println("Alphabet Frequency");
    
    // code that counts letters and outputs tally
    }

}
```

I have posted my code for the file reading bit.

Answer (score 1):

It is expected that your code reads only first line. Since you are using readLine() only once.

All you need to do is to have a loop and read the lines until there is no more line.

Here is the change that you need to do.

```
while((line=br.readLine())!=null)  
{  
 //your operations on this line 
}
```